# CSS - Triangle border not rendering correctly IE8

Tags: html, css, border, pseudo-element

I have a horizontal nav that has triangle borders inserted :before and :after a list item to make it appear as though there is a white bordered point on the right side of the list item. It's rendering in FF and Chrome but not IE8, and I'm using the html5 doctype and have included the html5.js.

It appears as though the list item background-color is stacked on top of the arrow border so it can't be seen because if I turn the background-color off I can see the arrow. I thought it might be a z-index problem but that doesn't help either. I also notice in IE that all of the :after styles are crossed out, any ideas?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
ul.registration-nav {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    width: 100%;
}
ul.registration-nav li {
  background-color: #afafaf;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 33%;
}
ul.registration-nav li.arrow:after { 
  content: " "; 
  display: block; 
  width: 0; 
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid #afafaf;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px; 
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 2; 
}
ul.registration-nav li.arrow:before { 
  content: " "; 
  display: block; 
  width: 0; 
  height: 0;
  border-top: 24px solid transparent;       
  border-bottom: 24px solid transparent;
  border-left: 18px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -24px; 
  margin-left: 1px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 1; 
}

ul.registration-nav li.checkout {
  background-color: #cecece;
}
ul.registration-nav li.active {
  background-color: #067673;
}
ul.registration-nav li.active:after {
  border-left: 15px solid #067673;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="nav inline registration-nav capitalize">
  <li class="register arrow active">Register</li>
  <li class="books arrow">Books</li>
  <li class="checkout">Checkout</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IE8 is not yet compatible with all the pseudo-elements introduced in CSS3.

Comment: You may have to wrap the text in a span, to give you another handle to attach a pseudoclass to, eg. `<li class="register arrow active"><span>Register</span></li>`. Then attach one of the arrows (presumably the one you want to render on top) to span:before, instead of :after on the <li> tags.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - Chris Coyier has an article on the after pseudo-selectors [here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after/)

Browser Support
Little issues:

- Firefox 3.5- wouldn't allow absolute positioning of pseudo elements.
- In Opera 9.2, whitespace is always displayed within this
  pseudo-element as if it’s pre text.
- IE 8 doesn't support z-index on them

So this very well could have been your problem.